# Regex for whole numbers or numbers with quarter decimal

Tags: regex, validation

I need a regex that only allows for whole numbers or numbers with a quarter decimal.

So far I have this, however this code `/[^.]+\.25|[^.]+\.50|[^.]+\.75|[^.]+\.00/` forces user to type a number with a decimal.  I'm looking for something more flexible.

Valid

```
0
0.
.25
.5
.75
3
1.
```

1.00
    5.0
    4.25
    8.50
    8.75

Invalid

```
1.2
.3
.
empty space
```

Comment: Try `^(?!\.?$)\d*\.?(?:[27]5|5?0?)?$`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/Nw5Amy/1

Comment: @revo Doesn't match `1.00`.

Comment: @melpomene I don't see it in samples or there is no explicit rule for it and I'm not supposed to read the regex from OP and find the rules. But if that's the case, it's just a matter of adding a character class `^(?!\.?$)\d*\.?(?:[27]5|[50]0?)?$`.

Comment: melpomene you are right, I did not account for 1.00 which would be valid.  Thanks for your efforts revo and  melpomene.

Answer (score 2):

You might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either an optional digit followed by a dot the quarter decimal part or match one or more digits followed by an optional dot.

[`^(?:\d*\.(?:[27]5|50?|00?)|\d+\.?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/8uiw84/1)

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d*\.` Match zero or more times a digit followed by a dot
  - `(?:[27]5|50?|00?)` Non capturing group which matches 25, 75, 50, 5, 0 or 00
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+\.?` Match one or more times a digit followed by an optional dot
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` Assert the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
/\A (?= \.? [0-9] ) [0-9]* (?: \. (?: [05]0? | [27]5 )? )? \z/x
```

Or with comments:

```
/
  \A  # beginning of string

  (?=  # look-ahead
    \.?    # a dot (optional)
    [0-9]  # a digit
  )
  # ^ this part ensures that there is at least one digit in the string.
  # in the following regex all parts are optional.

  [0-9]*  # the integer part: 0 or more digits
  (?:  # a group: the decimal part
    \.  # a dot
    (?:  # another group for digits after the decimal point
      [05]0?  # match 0 or 5, optionally followed by 0 (0, 00, 5, 50)
      |
      [27]5   # ... or 2 or 7, followed by 5 (25, 75)
    )?  # this part is optional
  )?  # ... actually, the whole decimal part is optional

  \z  # end of string
/x
```

It's a bit tricky because all parts of the number are optional in some way:

- `.25` is valid, so the integer part is optional
- `0` is valid, so the decimal point and following digits are optional
- `0.` is valid, so the decimal digits are optional

The main regex is written in a way that makes all parts optional, but there's a look-ahead assertion before it to make sure that the whole string is not empty or just `.`.